# UICollectionViewController with NSFetchedResultsController broke, when update property of all objects, if controller sorted on this property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have UICollectionViewController , It is collection view for some Objects at the map. So, I can update one item in fetched result (for example set LIKE for one of this Object). It is work well. I see changes immediately.
But if trying to update property "Distance" of all Objects, and same time controller are sorted on this property. Fetched result doesn't updated automatically. And then, while scrolling, reused Cells not updated, and I can see only Cells, that was on display, before I was started update property for all Objects. If I TouchUpInside first Cell in a row, for example it would be Object 123, controller open detail page of different Object, that Object, that should stay at this position after collectionView reloadData.

---

Incase I'm change Sort Descriptors from `[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[distanceAscending]];`

to  `[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[titleAscending]];`

or `[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[titleAscending, distanceAscending]];`

It is work well.

---

Incase I'm change property "Distance" of only one Object.
It is work well. Controller sort Cells as it should.

---

Incase I'm change property "Distance" of Objects not fetched this time.
It is work well.

---

Incase I'm close this controller, and open again `[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[distanceAscending]];` working as it should

---

I'm tying to reload CollectionViewController different ways,
`[self.collectionView reloadData];` and `reloadwithPredicateDefault`. But same result.

---

I'm tying to change Managed Object Context `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. But same result.

---

**MapObjectCollectionViewController.h**

```
@interface MapObjectCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController
```

**MapObjectCollectionViewController.m**

```
@interface MapObjectCollectionViewController ()<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPredicate * predicate1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSPredicate * predicate2;

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{


    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription* description =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MapObj"
                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:description];



        _predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"types.typeObjValue IN %@", self.selectionsTypes];
        _predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wiFi >= %i", 0]; 



    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[_predicate1, _predicate2]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


    NSSortDescriptor* titleAscending = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];

    NSSortDescriptor* distanceAscending = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:NO];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[distanceAscending]];
        // [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[titleAscending, distanceAscending]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
      atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
     newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    NSMutableDictionary *change = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            change[@(type)] = newIndexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            change[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            change[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            change[@(type)] = @[indexPath, newIndexPath];
            break;
    }
    [_itemChanges addObject:change];
}
- (void)reloadwithPredicateDefault {
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource
- (NSManagedObjectContext*) managedObjectContext {

    if (!_managedObjectContext) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[DataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        for (NSDictionary *change in self->_sectionChanges) {
            [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
                switch(type) {
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                        [self.collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]]];
                        break;
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                        [self.collectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]]];
                        break;
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                        break;
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                        break;
                }
            }];
        }
        for (NSDictionary *change in self->_itemChanges) {
            [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
                switch(type) {
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                        break;
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                        break;
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
                        break;
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                        [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:obj[0] toIndexPath:obj[1]];
                        break;
                }
            }];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self->_sectionChanges = nil;
        self->_itemChanges = nil;

    }];
}
```

**DataManager.h**

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *mainPrivateManagedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (DataManager*)sharedManager;
```

**DataManager.m**

```
@implementation DataManager

@synthesize mainPrivateManagedObjectContext = _mainPrivateManagedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

+(DataManager*) sharedManager{

    static DataManager* manager = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        manager = [[DataManager alloc] init];
    });

    return manager;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ProjectName" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProjectName.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    // NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
        // Report any error we got.

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]; //Удалить старую базу

        [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]; //Создать базу заново

    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        // . NSLog(@"get managedObjectContext");
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }

    _mainPrivateManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_mainPrivateManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setParentContext:_mainPrivateManagedObjectContext];
    // . NSLog(@"get return managedObjectContext");
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getContextForBGTask {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    [context setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    return context;
}
- (NSArray*) allMapObj {

    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription* description =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MapObj"
                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [request setEntity:description];

    NSError* requestError = nil;
    NSArray* resultArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError];
    if (requestError) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [requestError localizedDescription]);
    }
    return resultArray;
}
- (void)calculateDistanceWithCurrentLoaction:(CLLocation*) currentLoaction{
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext * bgcontext = [self getContextForBGTask];
    NSEntityDescription* description =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MapObj"
                inManagedObjectContext:bgcontext];

    [request setEntity:description];

    NSError* requestError = nil;
    NSArray* resultArray = [bgcontext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError];
    if (requestError) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [requestError localizedDescription]);
    }
    for (MapObj *mapObject in resultArray) {

            CLLocation *endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[mapObject.latitude doubleValue] longitude:[mapObject.longitude doubleValue]];
            CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLoaction distanceFromLocation:endLocation];
            mapObject.distance = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", distance]];

    }
    [bgcontext updatedObjects];
    [self saveContextForBGTask:bgcontext];

}
- (void)saveContextForBGTask:(NSManagedObjectContext *)bgTaskContext {
    if (bgTaskContext.hasChanges) {

        [bgTaskContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;

            [bgTaskContext save:&error];
        }];
        // Save default context
        [self saveDefaultContext:YES];
    }
}
- (void)saveDefaultContext:(BOOL)wait {
    if (_managedObjectContext.hasChanges) {
        [_managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            // . NSLog(@"managed context = %@", _managedObjectContext);
            NSError *error = nil;
            [self->_managedObjectContext save:&error];
        }];
    }
    void (^saveMainPrivateManagedObjectContext) (void) = ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self->_mainPrivateManagedObjectContext save:&error];
    };
    if ([_mainPrivateManagedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
        if (wait){
            // . NSLog(@"main context = %@", _mainPrivateManagedObjectContext);
            [_mainPrivateManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:saveMainPrivateManagedObjectContext];
        } else {
            [_mainPrivateManagedObjectContext performBlock:saveMainPrivateManagedObjectContext];
        }
    }
}
```

Error in console:

`2019-09-28 12:35:14.951873+0400 ProjectName[15695:4020487] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.140/UICollectionView.m:5972`

```
CoreData: fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to perform an insert and a move to the same index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xa945f4d4afea737e> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}) with userInfo (null)
```

What did I missed?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, was added:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
   [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
   ......
   if(self->_itemChanges.count > 1){
       [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
   } else {
       for (NSDictionary *change in self->_itemChanges) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ......
}
```